# Is this language decidable

Tags: turing-machines

`L={(〈M1〉,〈M2〉, x)|M1(x)` runs for strictly more steps than `M2(x)` does.

If both computations run forever, then neither takes strictly more steps than the other.

Is this language decidable or not? How to prove it?

Comment: As a hint, this one is undecidable. As a hint, have M1 be a machine that always loops, and see if you can have M2 be a machine whose behavior depends on whether some third TM M halts on a string w. (These questions tend to be a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com, by the way, but don't repost this specific question there since we discourage cross-posting.)

Answer (score 0):

As templatetypedef hints in the comment, this language is undecidable. If it were decidable, you could decide the halting problem as follows.

First, let M1 be any TM that fails to halt on input x. Such a TM might be a trivial one with two states that moves left and right and doesn't change the tape. Let M2 be any TM. A decider for your language now lets us answer the question "does M2 halt for all inputs", which is equivalent to the halting problem. You can also let M2 be a TM that first confirms any particular input w is on the tape, and then continues according to some TM M3. This would change the problem to "does M3 halt on input w", which is maybe the more canonical version of the problem.